# html2canvas converting only visible area of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing, html2canvas

i am using html2canvas plugin for this.

i am currently using this code.

```
 html2canvas($("#chartDiv"), {                              
  onrendered: function (canvas) {

   var win = window.open();
   win.document.write("<br><img src='" + canvas.toDataURL() + "'/>");
   win.print(); 
  }
});
```

when i convert the div to canvas, 
only the visible part of the window is turned into canvas.

i need to find a solution where i can print the div into many pages if the div
is over the size the window. ?

thank in advance

[image: this is my current output]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the only option you have is to modify the page to look the way you want the image to look before rendering.
I was facing the same problem when used html2canvas, and this is one of the reasons, why I write the methods that draw what I want to the canvas myself now.
Maybe have a look at [this](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/60)

Comment: i went through it, its hard luck. the example which one person has done is for an text in a div content, that works perfect. BUT in my case i am having a jOrg Chart which i have to print ..

Answer (score 0):

I was having same kind of issue to take image of Bootstrap Modal. The trick that worked for me was that I added a Temporary kind of `div` with `visibility:hidden` at the end of body like e.g.:

```
<div id="TempDataDiv" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
```

Then before calling `html2canvas` I added content to this `TempDataDiv` and removed content in `onrendered` function like below (two times to avoid cut at edges):

```
$("#TempDataDiv").html($("#chartDiv").html() + $("#chartDiv").html());

var useHeight = $("#chartDiv").prop('scrollHeight');

html2canvas($("#chartDiv"), {
    height: useHeight,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        imageData =  canvas.toDataURL();
        $("#TempDataDiv").html("");
        var win = window.open();
        win.document.write("<br><img src='" + imageData  + "'/>");
        win.print();
    }
});
```

I bit of a hack but worked fine for me.